# Notepad++ reloaded a file that wasn't saved on notepadd++ and was modified caused deleted info

Tags: notepad++, backup, reload, notepad

I had a file in Notepad++, I made changes in notepad++ and forgot to save there, no big deal since npp auto-saves it when you close it.
I accidentally changed the txt file via normal windows notepad and saved. (that caused the txt file to made changes on the original file before i made changes in npp). When I got back to npp I got the message that the file was modified somewhere else and asked me to reload it, again by accident I click 'reload'.
Is there a way to retrieve the data that was lost?

[image: Notepad Reload deleted data]

Answer (score 1):

If you use backup option in n++ preferences it will write to backup folder also not saved information.

Default backup folder in Windows system is:
*C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup*

Comment: my file isn't there. its location is in another Drive (drive E), can this be related?

Comment: do you have (had) active backup settings or not?

Comment: I did. "backup every 7 seconds", but i don't find it